# How can I change the RGBA of a ConsoleColor in a .NET Console app, with code?(esp:c#)

Tags: c#, colors, console-application

:)
I do some programing in my freetime so maybe it is a stupid question for someone.
But I'm really curious how can i bring more colour in a .net console app. 
I know there are only 16 colour(the ConsoleColors), so i cannot display more than 16 colour at once. However, I'm thinking about changing the RGBA of these. I mean, when I'm gonna use ConsoleColor.Blue; on the screen, it's orange. Is it possible?
I noticed, that I can change the RGBA in the Console Settings manually, when the console app is running, but I dont know how can i reach it with code.

I used the search button a million times but I found nothing. Now I'm hoping, You can help me with your opinoions,thought,comments.

Comment: "when I'm gonna use ConsoleColor.Blue; on the screen, it's orange." What is blue? What is orange?

Comment: Show the code you made so far.

Answer (score 0):

Open `cmd.exe`. Right click the menu bar and choose properties.

If you create a shortcut to `cmd.exe`, this shortcut can have different properties than your normal ones.

The wonderful blog 'Old new thing' [gives an example of how you can change this shortcuts properties via c++ and win32/COM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130527-00/?p=4253). Translating this to .Net and P/Invoke is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Why not use a way the author of this question wants (by changing the color via code)? Quote: `"but I dont know how can i reach it with code."`